How can "feeling" occur *after* "forms" in the 5 Aggregates Framework (5 skandhas)?
Looking at https://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=Five_skandhas, how is it possible that the feeling is derived out of the forms? If the forms don't have feeling themselves, how can feeling emerge from non-feeling basically?
I would think the order is reversed, where first there are feelings, and the feelings create forms ("name" things, so to speak). So why does this say forms -> feelings instead of feelings -> forms?

The five aggregates is not a sequence. It's a list, a group.

Part 1
As the article says, they are aggregates.(what it made of). One doesn't generate other /others.
Part 2

how is it possible that the feeling is derived out of the forms? If the forms don't have feeling themselves, how can feeling emerge from non-feeling basically?

Rupa (Material Form).
Forms means rupa.
There are 28 rupas.
Reference 1
Reference 2
Reference 3
Forms means rupa. One of which is the image that is created inside eye(or sound ect). Images themselves doesn't have any feelings. That's because these images are just reflection of what is in front of the eye.(reflection inside eye, ect) . The reflection of the physical objects outside of the eye. Now, do these images have any feelings (how can a reflection of a image have a feeling, other than color, ect) to it?
No. Right?
So, after image is created as a thought. Then, that's where feelings are generated about an image. Feeling can't be generated about nothing. Some image should be there for feelings to be generated about.

If the forms don't have feeling themselves, how can feeling emerge from non-feeling basically?

Using past memories (automatically), past experiences, past karma. That's how feelings are generated. Rupa/forms doesn't have feelings in themselves. The mind generates feelings for nun feelings objects, using past karma, past experiences and past memories.

The five aggregates are used to explain the causes of clinging and suffering. They are not a reason or the cause of one another.

So if i strike your head with a baseball bat, you are suggesting the painful feelings are not related to the body & its nervous system but, instead, are a creation of the mind? The mind, for whatever reason, decides the baseball bat cracking open your skull "hurts"? The pain is not related to the skull bones cracking open and blood & brainy matter oozing out? So when you end up in hospital and are given pain killers, such as morpheine, the reduction of pain is not biological phenomena but, instead, something the mind decides to occur? The mind decides the morpheine will reduce the pain. Then when an anethseitic is administered for the skull & brain surgery, it is the mind that decides to put itself to sleep? So the physical pain, the blood & brainy matter, the morpheine and the anethseitic are not "biological phenomena" but, instead, mere mind created mental images?
The Pali suttas say:

And what are the two feelings? Physical and mental. These are called the two feelings.
SN 36.22.


The six classes of feeling should be known.' Thus was it said. In reference to what was it said? Dependent on the eye & forms there arises consciousness at the eye. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as a requisite condition there is feeling. Dependent on the ear & sounds there arises consciousness at the ear. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as a requisite condition there is feeling. Dependent on the nose & aromas there arises consciousness at the nose. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as a requisite condition there is feeling. Dependent on the tongue & flavors there arises consciousness at the tongue. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as a requisite condition there is feeling. Dependent on the body & tactile sensations there arises consciousness at the body. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as a requisite condition there is feeling. Dependent on the intellect & ideas there arises consciousness at the intellect. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as a requisite condition there is feeling. 'The six classes of feeling should be known.' Thus was it said. And in reference to this was it said. This is the fifth sextet.
MN 148


Why you down vote my answer? Did you read it? The mind, for whatever reason, decides the baseball bat cracking your skull "hurts"? No. It's a chemical process. Neurons transfer the signal to the brain from damaged tissue. So when you end up in hospital and are given pain killers, such as morpheine, the reduction of pain is not biological phenomena but, instead, something the mind decides to occur? No. They inhibit the neuron signal path. They doesn't effect the mind.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
